# insert multiple records in zend framework2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

insert values using foreach loop in zend framework 2 not working, only last value does save.

```
foreach($meta_defined as $key => $value){
    $meta->setProperty('page',$meta_id);
    $meta->setProperty('metakey',$value['meta_key']);
    $meta->setProperty('metavalue',$post[$value['meta_key']]);
    $meta->setProperty('type', '0');
    $dm->persist($meta);
    $dm->flush($meta);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constantly overwriting the same Entity and saving it, additionally you flush more than once which is not neccessary. Do it like this:

```
foreach ($someData as $k=>$v) {
    $obj = new Object();
    $obj->setFoo($v);
    $dm->persist($obj);
}

$dm->flush();
```